# Cumulative variable calculation which is reset under a given condition, for each ID - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I want to create a cumulative variable based on a non-cumulative variable. This variable should be reset when the value of Y equals 1 (but the reset will start from the row below).
I want to do that for each ID in the data frame.

Data illustration:

```
ID  X   Non_cum Y
A   ..  0       0
A   ..  20      0
A   ..  40      0
B   ..  0       0
B   ..  100     0
B   ..  200     1
B   ..  50      0
```

Expected result:

```
ID  X   Non_cum Y   Cum
A   ..  0       0   0
A   ..  20      0   20
A   ..  40      0   60
B   ..  0       0   0
B   ..  100     0   100
B   ..  200     1   300
B   ..  50      0   50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `ID` and cumsum of `Y` (with shift):

```
groups = df.groupby(['ID'])

df['Y_block'] = groups['Y'].shift(fill_value=0)
df['Y_block'] = groups['Y_block'].cumsum()

df['Cum'] = df.groupby(['ID','Y_block'])['Non_cum'].cumsum()
```

Output (`Cum` column):

```
0      0
1     20
2     60
3      0
4    100
5    300
6     50
Name: Cum, dtype: int64
```